# ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41) Unhandled Exception: type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'DateTime'

Tags: flutter, api, dart

I have been trying to create a simple API fetching app and suddenly stoped getting fetched. Debug console shows the below error.
[image]

Codes

[image]

Debug error

[image]

First time it worked fine and now I couldn't identify the issue. Pls. help me with this

Comment: you are getting null from map, check response data & can you include code-snippet instead of code-image

Answer (score 1):

Better will be having nullable dataType on `DateTime?`. this way you can accept null value and do a null check UI while using it.

```
final DateTime? bdate;
```

Also you can provide default dateTime on null-case which isn't preferable

```dart
bdate: json['bdate']?? DateTime.now(), ///having current date on null case
```